# How to monitor mqtt connection in Spring Integration application

Tags: spring, connection, mqtt, integration, paho

I'm building a Spring Integration application with mqtt and tcp connections.
For the mqtt part, I need to check the status of the connection in a scheduled way.

Is there any way to retrieve the status of the connection using Mqttv5PahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter or Mqttv5PahoMessageHandler?
Since access to the underlying mqttClient is blocked, I don't know how to do it..